# how to return object from array with highest key values along with name?

Tags: javascript

As I'm trying to get an object with all the names with the highest values, I am only getting one value and name rather than all existing names with the same highest value? // { name: 'Stephen', total: 85 } 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
const students = [
{ name: 'Andy', total: 40 },
{ name: 'Seric', total: 50 },
{ name: 'Stephen', total: 85 },
{ name: 'David', total: 30 },
{ name: 'Phil', total: 40 },
{ name: 'Eric', total: 85 },
{ name: 'Cameron', total: 30 },
{ name: 'Geoff', total: 30 }];

const max = Math.max(...students.map(e => e.total))

const result = students.find(student => student.total === max)

console.log(result)//{ name: 'Stephen', total: 85 }
```

Comment: If performance does matter for your use case, you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395659/11299053) below as it avoids looping twice over source array (to evaluate maximum `total` and to find out owners of max `total`). If that suits better to the purpose, upvote/accept are greatly welcome ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
const result = students.filter(student => student.total == max)
```

Comment: Even though that one delivers expected output, there's a [faster way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395659/11299053), avoiding unnecessary looping to evaluate `max`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using a single `forEach` loop, which returns an array of the top students.

```js
const students = [{ name: 'Andy', total: 40 },{ name: 'Seric', total: 50 },{ name: 'Stephen', total: 85 },{ name: 'David', total: 30 },{ name: 'Phil', total: 40 },{ name: 'Eric', total: 85 },{ name: 'Cameron', total: 30 },{ name: 'Geoff', total: 30 }];

const findTop = (students) => {
  let max = 0;
  let top = [];

  students.forEach(student => {
    if (student.total > max) {
      max = student.total;
      top = [student];
    } else if (student.total === max) {
      top.push(student);
    }
  })
  
  return top;
};

console.log(findTop(students));
```

Comment: No offence, but this one looks to me like a slightly more verbose and a bit suboptimal (due to re-creating resulting array upon each cycle) copy of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395659/11299053).

Comment: I had thought about wrapping it in function for some additional optimizations, I'll do that.

Comment: Now it has perfect readability on the upside and broken logic in case of negative `total` (which doesn't seem to be the case, though) on the downside, of course, if you don't want to use ugly `-Infinity` for the sake of algorithm robustness.

Comment: I assumed a student couldn't have a negative grade, which is usually the case. That value could be tweaked if using some odd grading system.

Comment: However, now it's clean and readable, thus deserves an upvote from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop with reduce by returning the object with the greatest `total`.

```js
const
    students = [{ name: 'Andy', total: 40 }, { name: 'Seric', total: 50 }, { name: 'Stephen', total: 85 }, { name: 'David', total: 30 }, { name: 'Phil', total: 40 }, { name: 'Eric', total: 85 }, { name: 'Cameron', total: 30 }, { name: 'Geoff', total: 30 }]
    highest = students.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r || r[0].total < o.total) return [o];
        if (r[0].total === o.total) r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(highest);
```

Comment: OP's problem was to find out *all* owners of the max 'total', finding single winner is what he already achieved (in more efficient manner, by the way, using `find()`). You're right, though, `reduce()` is a very powerful thing, so [it may solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395659/11299053) the problem even better than OP does expect.

Comment: right. but op need two iterations instead of an optimized one.

Comment: @NinaScholz : check out my solution in that regard

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, sorry didn't read the question in depth ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One pass over the array is absolutely enough to do the job with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const students=[{name:'Andy',total:40},{name:'Seric',total:50},{name:'Stephen',total:85},{name:'David',total:30},{name:'Phil',total:40},{name:'Eric',total:85},{name:'Cameron',total:30},{name:'Geoff',total:30}],
      result = students.reduce((res,student,idx) => (
        !idx || student.total > res[0]['total'] ?
        res = [student] :
        student.total == res[0]['total'] ?
        res.push(student) :
        true
      , res),[])
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```